# Android.Views.InflateException: 'Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar'

Tags: xamarin.forms

After updating my app from `FormsApplicationActivity` to `FormsAppCompatActivity`, I get the following exception thrown in `base.OnCreate(bundle)`:

```
Android.Views.InflateException: 'Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar'
```

This seems to come from my `layout/Toolbar.xml` file, which I have not changed from the default.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

The funny thing is, if I create a new project, it works. As far as I can tell, everything is exactly the same between my old upgraded project and the brand new one.

Things I've tried:

- Add `Theme = "@style/MainTheme"` to the `[Activity]` attribute
- Add `android:theme="@style/MainTheme"` to the `<application>` tag of `AndroidManifest.xml`
- Add

  ```
  TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
  ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
  ```

  to `OnCreate()`
- Copy `styles.xml`, `colors.xml`, `Toolbar.xml`, `Tabbar.xml` from the working project into the old project
- Clean solution + delete `bin`/`obj` folders + rebuild
- Doing a diff between the `.csproj` files and replacing almost everything from the working file into the bad file
- Completely uninstall Xamarin Forms and all AndroidX dependencies, then reinstall from NuGet. The AndroidX dependencies were not readded, which matches the newly created project

None of it worked.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the exception is actually harmless.  It appears to be caught inside `base.OnCreate()` and handled, not bubbled up to my code.

You can stop the debugger from breaking by going to `Debug --> Windows --> Exception Settings`, and unchecking `Common Language Runtime Exceptions --> <All Common Runtime Language Exceptions not in this list`

Unfortunately, unlike normal C# development, Xamarin seems to have no option for "only break on unhandled exceptions" :(

---

[Edit] In VS 2022 there is [a bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS-2022-breaking-on-caught-exception-ev/1650854?space=8&scope=follow) causing exceptions to break even when you tell it not to.  I'm not aware of any workaround.  Sigh.

Answer (score 1):

I also just came across this issue when upgrading from `FormsApplicationActivity` to `FormsAppCompatActivity`

The fix for me was adding `Droid/Resources/values/styles.xml` from the blank template app:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  <!-- can be empty in this tag, or have your project config -->
  </style>
</resources>
```

This was added as a transform file in the csproj:

```xml
<TransformFile Include="Resources\values\styles.xml" />
```

I then had to update my main activity attribute

```cs
[Activity(
    ...
    Theme = "@style/MainTheme",
    ...)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
```

Comment: Been confounding me for days.  
Today - a link to this came up in the search results.
Thank you - you saved the life of a laptop.